# Docker permission denied when running npm run build

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, tsc, npm-run

I'm a newbie with docker. I'm trying to deploy a docker container to Azure. When running npm install everything works fine, but when npm run build is executed there is the following error message:

sh: 1: tsc: Permission denied

I already tried to give extra permissions using chmod. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Please provide your Dockerfile so we can understand better and provide help,
In general, you can add USER root at the top of the Dockerfile.